# Effect of contraction on Levy-Prokhorov metric

Tags: probability-theory

I think the following lemma is true and it is not difficult to prove:

*Let $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ be two metric spaces and $\mu$ and $\nu$ be probability measures on $\mathcal{X}$. Furthermore, assume that $T: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is a contraction. Then, if $\tilde{\mu}$ and $\tilde{\nu}$ are pushforward of $\mu$ and $\nu$ under $T$ respectively, then we have $d_\text{LP}(\tilde{\mu}, \tilde{\nu}) \leq d_\text{LP}(\mu, \nu)$. Here, $d_\text{LP}$ denotes the Levy-Prokhorov metric.*

If one follows the definition of Levy-Prokhorv metric, the proof should be straightforward. However, I am looking for a reference for this lemma to avoid writing it as a separate lemma in a document. I could not find it in the literature unfortunately. If anyone know of a reference for this statement, I appreciate it if they can share it with me.